# Rails Nokogiri html parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, python-2.7, nokogiri

I have `aws-lambda` function written like below and it returns the html content. 
    import urllib2
    import json

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement

    req_url = event['url']
    header = {"User-Agent" : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    response = ""
    try:
        request = urllib2.Request(req_url, headers=header)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    except:
        response = "404 called"
    return response
```

And I parse this in `Rails`

```
resp = lambda.invoke(function_name: 'lambda_crawl', payload: s )
content = resp['payload'].read 
content_get = Nokogiri::HTML(content)
```

However, in `content_get`, there are something incomprehensible encoding problem. `<li class='\"rank01\"'>` if print `content_get` it shows like this so `at_css` or `xpath` method of `Nokogiri` doesn't fit.

I am not sure why this kinds of thing happens. I tried to strip out slashes, but unicode characters exists in contents `\u306e\u8a9e` so this cannot be the solution. Also encoding check also shows that it is encoded as 'utf-8'

What is the origin of this problem?

Comment: What does `content` look like?

Comment: the problem is as I mentioned all of the values are overlapped with '\"rank01\"' weird '\ \' things

Comment: I think it'll help if you show `content` for people to figure out why this happens.

Comment: It's so weird to me that you would mix ruby and python like this. Also lambda is such a bad choice for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was solved by using `node.js` handler in lambda, thereby getting exact contents from html request.